# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject (Android)

Tags: java, php, android

I've been trying to use a JSONParser to access a remote database using php. However i have an error that i do not know how to solve. Could someone have a look over the code please. I've heard about the 3 characters at the start of a jsonString but i'm not sure how to fix it.

```
public class JSONParser {
        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";
        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {
        }
        public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {
            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                // Extract data from the response.
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                // Open an inputStream with the data content.
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
                String line = null;
                // Build the string until null.
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                // Close the input stream.
                is.close();
                // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            } 
            // Return the JSON Object.
            return jObj;
        }
        // function get json from url
        // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
        public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,List<NameValuePair> params) {
            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // check for request method
                if(method == "POST"){
                    // request method is POST
                    // defaultHttpClient
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();
                }else if(method == "GET"){
                    // request method is GET
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();
                }          
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            // return JSON String
            return jObj;
        }
    }
```

LogCat error:

```
E/JSON Parser(27286): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Just though i'd add the php code that i'm using for the register function:

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

// If posted data is not empty
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    // If the username or password submition is empty
    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        // Create a JSON response
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please enter a username and a password.";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    // Check to see if there is already a user with the username
    $query = " SELECT 1 FROM registration where username = :user";
    // update the empty :user variable
    $query_params = array(':user' => $_POST['username']);
    // run query against database
    try
    {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    //return username data if already in use
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if($row)
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, this username is already in use";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    // Query to create a user
    $query = "Insert INTO registration (username, password) VALUES (:user, :password)";
    // Update variables with actual data
    $query_params = array(':user' => $_POST['username'], ':pass' => $_POST['password']);
    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Errror2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    // By this point, user has been added
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
?>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="register.php method="post+>
        Username:<br />
        <input type = "text" name="username" value ="" />
        <br /><br />
        Password:<br />
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Register New User" />
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: the response is  string not a json. check the same on the server side

Comment: please post the response string which you are getting from the server.
As the exception says...its is not a JSON.